# Clarification on why the following SQL ROLLBACK command causes an error?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, rollback

I'm studying SQL, and the test prep question has a user-session like so :

```
CREATE TABLE product (pcode NUMBER(2), pname VARCHAR2(10) );
INSERT INTO product VALUES (1, 'pen');
INSERT INTO product VALUES (2, 'pencil');
SAVEPOINT a;
UPDATE product SET pcode = 10 WHERE pcode = 1;
SAVEPOINT b;
DELETE FROM product WHERE pcode = 2;
COMMIT; 
SQL> DELETE FROM product WHERE pcode = 10;
```

After the above we then run this command :

```
ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT a
```

according to the test -guide, this generates an error; also - no SQL statement is rolled back.

why is this?

Comment: where is the rollback command? also - is this oracle?

Comment: @benji - thanks, added a missing detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are running a `commit` command what happens is that your earlier `savepoint`s get erased and you can't rollback to a your savepoint.

Try to remove the commit and rerun the script.